sqlmap showing error when i tried to solve dvwa (damn vulnerable web application) blind sql injection on easy mode
when i try to solve dvwa "blind sql injection mode" in easy level i have to work through sqlmap on kali linux, then i intercept the submit request in burpsuite and copy the request and name it reqq.txtt using nano editer and save it, the intercepted request look like this
GET /dvwa/vulnerabilities/sqli_blind/?id=2&Submit=Submit&user_token=6090f944ef4e26bd92a9480a568f5975 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: close
Referer: http://localhost/dvwa/vulnerabilities/sqli_blind/
Cookie: language=en; welcomebanner_status=dismiss; cookieconsent_status=dismiss; PHPSESSID=t10lmb7k592c49hgbq1a6ecip0; security=impossible
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

then i execute the command on terminal.
sqlmap -r reqq.txtt
and then sqlmap encountered the problem,
[CRITICAL] all tested parameters do not appear to be injectable. Try to increase values for '--level'/'--risk' options if you wish to perform more tests. If you suspect that there is some kind of protection mechanism involved (e.g. WAF) maybe you could try to use option '--tamper' (e.g. '--tamper=space2comment') and/or switch '--random-agent'

please everyone im totally new here to share the problem with you guys, help me to wipe out this problem ...
thank you in advance
i hope you guys will help me

i also tried to increase values but it didnt work

You are not in "easy mode".
Set your cookie from security=impossible to security=low.
